# Auto trim values for varchar on insert

Tags: mysql, csv

Is there an equivalent option to *SET ANSI_PADDING* from ms-sql for mysql, or another way to auto-trim values inserted to a varchar-field from a csv file with *LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'foo.csv'* ?

Comment: You could do a trigger to do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may manipulate imported files during LOAD DATA by using SET combined with one or multiple string functions. Here's an example that trims a column during import as well as removing any newlines

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'foo.csv' 
INTO TABLE db.footable
(foocolumn)
SET foocolumn = TRIM(foocolumn), 
foocolumn = REPLACE(foocolumn, "\n", " ") 
;
```